# How to centre image in absolute div

Tags: html, css

Hello how can I center this magnify when I hover an image?
Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/585/):

```
.portfolio-bt{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -29px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border:1px solid #fff;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
.portfolio-bt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:470px;
    height:380px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cyCFS/586/)

Comment: Here's also a useful link that expands on this answer: [Smashing Magazine "Absolute Horizontal and Vertical Centering in CSS"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Comment: But I want that button look like in my example and be centered.